# How to convert string to bytes in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

I know this may sounds like a duplicate question, but that's because I don't know how to describe this question properly.

For some reason I got a bunch of unicode string like this:

```
a = u'\xcb\xea'
```

As you can see, it's actually bytes representation of a Chinese character, encoding in `gbk`

```
>>> print(b'\xcb\xea'.decode('gbk'))
岁
```

`u'岁'` is what I need, but I don't know how to convert `u'\xcb\xea'` to `b'\xcb\xea'`.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really a bytes representation, it's still unicode codepoints. They are the wrong codepoints, because it was decoded from bytes as if it was encoded to Latin-1.

Encode to Latin 1 (whose codepoints map one-on-one to bytes), then decode as GBK:

```
a.encode('latin1').decode('gbk')
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = u'\xcb\xea'
>>> a.encode('latin1').decode('gbk')
u'\u5c81'
>>> print a.encode('latin1').decode('gbk')
岁
```

Comment: Amazing, that's the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way for python2 is to use the `repr()`:

```
>>> key_unicode = u'uuuu\xf6\x9f_\xa1\x05\xeb9\xd4\xa3\xd1'
>>> key_ascii = 'uuuu\xf6\x9f_\xa1\x05\xeb9\xd4\xa3\xd1'
>>> print(key_ascii)
uuuu��_��9ԣ�
>>> print(key_unicode)
uuuuö_¡ë9Ô£Ñ
>>>
>>> # here is the save method for both string types:
>>> print(repr(key_ascii).lstrip('u')[1:-1])
uuuu\xf6\x9f_\xa1\x05\xeb9\xd4\xa3\xd1
>>> print(repr(key_unicode).lstrip('u')[1:-1])
uuuu\xf6\x9f_\xa1\x05\xeb9\xd4\xa3\xd1
>>> # ____________WARNING!______________
>>> # if you will use jsut `str.strip('u\'\"')`, you will lose
>>> # the "uuuu" (and quotes, if such are present) on sides of the string:
>>> print(repr(key_unicode).strip('u\'\"'))
\xf6\x9f_\xa1\x05\xeb9\xd4\xa3\xd1
```

For python3 use `str.encode()` to get the bytes type.

```
>>> key = 'l\xf6\x9f_\xa1\x05\xeb9\xd4\xa3\xd1q\xf5L\xa9\xdd0\x90\x8b\xf5ht\x86za\x0e\x1b\xed\xb6(\xaa+'
>>> key
'lö\x9f_¡\x05ë9Ô£ÑqõL©Ý0\x90\x8bõht\x86za\x0e\x1bí¶(ª+'
>>> print(key)
lö_¡ë9Ô£ÑqõL©Ý0õhtzaí¶(ª+
>>> print(repr(key.encode()).lstrip('b')[1:-1])
l\xc3\xb6\xc2\x9f_\xc2\xa1\x05\xc3\xab9\xc3\x94\xc2\xa3\xc3\x91
```